# Reload/Update View In Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm busy making an app with an account page. I want that users can logon via that page and as soon as they have done so successfully that the page reloads to display their account information rather than the standard message stating that they have to logon to make use of the page.

However when I get sent back to the account page from logging on the view doesn't really update. So therefore I am wondering if I can't reload the view after certain buttons are pressed that can check again wether the user is logged on or not and deal accordingly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

if you want to trigger layouting or just drawing there is `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay`

**There is no built-in method to reload custom data** (on iOS)

---

so do a reload and inside a reload -- call setNeedsDisplay

```
import UIKit

protocol MyViewDelegate {
    func viewString() -> String;
}

class MyView : UIView {
    var myViewDelegate : MyViewDelegate?
    private var str : String?

    func reloadData() {
        if myViewDelegate != nil {
            str = myViewDelegate!.viewString()
        }
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        UIRectFill(self.bounds)
        if str != nil {
            let ns = str! as NSString
            ns.drawInRect(self.bounds, withAttributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)])
        }
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, MyViewDelegate {
    func viewString() -> String {
        return "blabla"
    }

    var v : MyView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        v = MyView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.view.addSubview(v)

        v.myViewDelegate = self;
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        v.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could show me an example because I do not completely understand what you mean with this.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift use this,

If you wants to  reload the UIView present in the viewController just use NotificationCenter.

In ViewController class add this in viewWillAppear

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)  {
       //Trigger notification
       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "update"), object: nil)

        }
```

In UIView  class add Observer for the notification

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     //Add Observer
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "update"), object: nil)

   }

 @objc func updateList(){
    //write Reload data here......
      tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

Comment: It will reload tableView only, not the entire view.

Answer (score -6):

The Swift have really advanced itself and for many people if they don't know we can refresh the whole view with just one simple line of code.

`viewWillAppear(true)`

Comment: I haven't been able to play around with Swift for some time now, but even then, I am pretty sure that this won't work unless you put all the refreshing logic in the viewWillAppear function, in which case you might as well make a different function and call that one.